# How do store the value of quotient while dividing two variables of dataypes BigIntger and int?

Tags: java, biginteger

i am trying to print the value of quotient while dividing a BigInteger variable by an integer variable, but the compiler shows "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - bad operand types for binary operator '/' first type:  java.math.BigInteger second type: int"

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s;
    BigInteger n, repeat, remainder;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    s=in.nextLine();
    n=in.nextBigInteger();
    repeat=n/s.length();
    System.out.println(repeat);
 }
```

Comment: Cast the int to a big int, then do big int arithmetic and store into a big int then use big int methods to output the result.

Comment: Can you paste your code here?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String s;
        BigInteger n, repeat, remainder;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        s=in.nextLine();
        n=in.nextBigInteger();
        repeat=n/s.length();
        System.out.println(repeat);
        
       
      
    
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert the int to BigInteger.
2. Use the BigInteger.divide method to perform the operation.  (/ operand works only with primitive types.)

   ```
   import java.math.BigInteger;
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class ModuloTest {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           String s;
           BigInteger n, repeat, remainder;
           Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
           s = in.nextLine();
           n = in.nextBigInteger();
           BigInteger length = BigInteger.valueOf(s.length());
           repeat = n.divide(length);

           System.out.println(repeat);
       }

   }
   ```